# Why is Yii giving my 400 Bad Request?

Tags: php, yii, controller

For some reason I'm getting `400 Bad Request` when calling a controller.

This functions works fine and returns data:

```
lib.getAjax('/address/getDuplicates','').done(function(response){});
```

This functions however triggers a `400 Bad Request`:

```
lib.setAjax(url,data).done(function(response){});
```

My route looks like this:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
```

And my functions in `AddressController` looks like this:

```
public function actionGetDuplicates(){
    $result = Address::getDuplicates();
    ApplicationPlugin::sendAjaxResponse($result);
}

public function actionMergeDuplicates(){
    $requestData = ApplicationPlugin::getRequestData(array('primaryStreetID, selectedRows'));
    $result= Address::mergeDuplicates($requestData->primaryStreetID, $requestData->selectedRows);

    ApplicationPlugin::sendAjaxResponse($result);
}
```

Comment: No, I'm working on Windows and it has nothing to do with the Apache web server.

Comment: Do you use **enableCsrfValidation** (`enableCsrfValidation' => true` in main config)?

Comment: Which action returns 400 error(**actionGetDuplicates()** or **actionMergeDuplicates()**)?

Comment: I have no idea what that is. I'm not a core Yii developer. I'm using `lib.setAjax()` in many other functions and never had problems with this before. Calling **actionMergeDuplicates** gives me the error.

Comment: Ok. Try to check action without ajax. For example, set something like `echo 11111` in your action and call your route from browser. And change **actionMergeDuplicates** to **actionMergeduplicates** etc. Because unix case sensitive. It's works only on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found my error.

In my controller I was doing this:

```
$requestData = ApplicationPlugin::getRequestData(array('primaryStreetID, selectedRows'));
```

when I must do this:

```
$requestData = ApplicationPlugin::getRequestData(array('primaryStreetID', 'selectedRows'));
```

This is what caused the `400 bad request`

Comment: sorry, but what did you changed both lines are identical?